# What are the pitfalls and caveats of global variables in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables

A demo app for an SDK I'm looking at has global variables for the application delegate, and the root view controller.

I haven't seen this before, but the advantages are obvious. 
Any shortcut around retyping

```
AViewController* rootVC = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

just to get the root view controller seems like a huge help.

But of course, with any seemingly huge advantage always comes equal disadvantage. So why shouldn't I always make a global variable in AppDelegate.m for my app delegate and root view controller? Does it waste resources or compromise security?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the root view controller to each controller that requires it? If everything requires it then your design could be better.

Comment: Passing meaning `#import` or overriding an init method? And I have no problem with that, I'm just wondering why globals are not optimal design.

Comment: Passing means a property. Globals increase cross coupling and dependence. The app delegate has a purpose and that purpose is not for all controllers to keep accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad practice because it leads to unmaintainable or difficult to maintain code.

- Race conditions are really easy to come by as two parts of the application attempt to modify the same global variable and you have to assure yourself things are done in a certain order.
- Program logic can be confusing at times as values are changed
  underneath you by a different part of the application. You always
  have to think about how you changing a certain value affects
  everything else that is using that variable and what state they might
  be in.
- You still have to pass around a reference to the global object or
  refer to the parent controller to grab a reference. Which makes your 
  code very dependent and not as robust as code that is designed to be 
  standalone with values passed in.

These points are very generalized, but should at least give you an indication of why most people prefer to avoid the global scope and instead go with a decoupled design.

Answer (score 1):

If you frequently access your root view controller via the shared app delegate, then you might was well add a global variable as a shortcut. It's essentially the same thing. It doesn't waste resources or compromise security.

That said, I would argue that it encourages bad design. Instead of accessing a global variable, why not pass references only to the controllers that need them? Or perhaps work on decoupling your controllers with NSNotifications, delegates, or block callbacks?

It's up to you based on your app's needs. Try to walk the line between over-engineering and a good, decoupled design.